# Three mysql triggers

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

```
       delimiter //
create trigger logsupdate before update on users
for each row 
begin
  if new.pJailed <> old.pJailed then
    set new.jailtime = now();
     if new.pVIP <> old.pVIP then
    set new.TM2 = now();
         if new.pAdminLevel <> old.pAdminLevel then
    set new.TM3 = now();
  end if;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

Why shouldn't this work? I tried to fallow an answer from previous question but it gives me errors here.

MYSQL ERROR

```
create trigger logsupdate before update on users
for each row 
begin
  if new.pJailed <> old.pJailed then
    set new.jailtime = now();
     if new.pVIP <> old.pVIP then
    set new.TM2 = now();
         if new.pAdminLevel <> old.pAdminLevel then
    set new.TM3 = now();
  end if;
end;
MySQL says: DOCUMENTATION

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11
```

Comment: You really should be describing your problem in more detail that "doesn't work".

Comment: @Uueerdo done. My thoughts are that the code should've finished at  the first "set". But as I need three delimiters I've added them in the same code and it does not recognise in SQL.

Comment: remove the semicolon in `end;//`

Comment: It looks like you're missing and `end if`

Comment: also `end;` needs to be `end//`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a couple of `end if;`. Also, semicolon is not required in `end;//`. I have also added a `Drop Trigger If Exists` clause to avoid errors, in case a duplicate trigger with this name already exists.

Here is the corrected trigger (based on [OP's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412669/three-mysql-triggers#comment91770045_52412851)):

```
delimiter //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS logsupdate //
create trigger logsupdate before update on users
for each row 
begin

  if new.pJailed <> old.pJailed then
    set new.jailtime = now();
  end if;

  if new.pVIP <> old.pVIP then
    set new.TM2 = now();
  end if;

  if new.pAdminLevel <> old.pAdminLevel then
    set new.TM3 = now();
  end if;
end//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: That actually makes sense. I thought for a second that "if" needs only one "end if". Non-sense mistake made by me, thanks for evidencing that. :)

Comment: @AlxTioltisan no worries. Happy to help :) We all have been there !

Comment: I have just updated the "pAdminLevel" row and TM3 it won't actualise. Any clue why?

Comment: @AlxTioltisan It is because pJailed and pVIP also needs to be updated before it can go to the third level of If condition.

Comment: How can I eliminate levels of condition? I want three different delimiters without depending one of each other. I should rewrite the whole code? Because as I can see, at "pJailed" row I have no trouble. It updates the "jailtimer"